# Select multiple columns from multiple tables?

Tags: sql

I have 3 tables in sql

**PTable**:

```
Prdnum
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
```

**Qtable**:

```
prdnum        Pid             Data

1              1             somedata
1              2             somedata
2              1             somedata
3              1             somedata
3              2             somedata
4              1             somedata
```

**STable**:

```
Prdnum                      brand
1                           somedata
2                           somedata
3                           somedata 
4                           somedata
```

The `Prdnum` is the primary key. Here I need to select the `Prdnum` from `PTable` and brand belongs `Prdnum` from `Stable` and `Data` from `QTable` belongs to `Prdnum`, and another condition is the `Prdnum` don't having `Pid=2` in `QTable`.

I tried some code like

```
SELECT Prdnum 
FROM PTable 
WHERE Prdnum NOT IN (SELECT Prdnum FROM QTable WHERE Pid=2)
```

but how can I select `Brand` and `Data` from other tables?

Comment: try a join ...maybe ?

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Learn about ANSI 92 joins.  Visual explanation [here](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT p.Prdnum, s.Brand, q.Data
FROM PTable p
JOIN STable s on p.Prdnum = s.Prdnum
JOIN QTable q on p.Prdnum = q.Prdnum
WHERE q.Pid != 2
```

Comment: @user2318361 odd.. what data type is Pid? if it's `varchar` try `'2'` instead of just `2`

Comment: I tried this based on you answer and I got the required answer ..

Thanks a lot Sir  


SELECT  REPLACE(P.Prdnum, '', '')AS ITEMNUMBER,S.BRAND,Q.Data
 FROM PTable P JOIN QTable Q ON P.Prdnum=Q.Prdnum 
 JOIN STable S ON P.Prdnum=S.Prdnum

 WHERE P.PrdnumNOT IN(SELECT N.Prdnum FROM QTable N WHERE N.Pid=2)

Answer (score 2):

```
select * 
from Qtable
inner join STable 
on Qtable.prdnum = STable.prdnum
where (Qtable.prdnum <> 2);
```

I ignored PTable, you can include it in case there are products in this table not available in the 2 other tables (using an outer join)